# Trigger onChange event of Kendo Editor widget

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

Suppose I have the following kendo-editor:

```
<div kendo-editor ng-model="name" k-options="editorOptions"></div>
```

Then, I have the following `editorOptions`:

```
function onChange(e) {
   alert("I am changing.");
}
$scope.editorOptions = { change: onChange };
```

How can I access the actual kendo-editor object for me to trigger the onChange event without using the normal jQuery selection:

Example: `$("#myEditor").kendoEditor().trigger("change")`

Answer (score 1):

You must define control reference in current scope (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#getting-widget-references) and you can define events as an attribute:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div kendo-editor="kendoEditorControl" ng-model="name" k-options="editorOptions" k-on-change="onChange()"></div>
</div>
<script>
  angular.module("app", [ "kendo.directives" ]).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.onChange = function() {
     alert($scope.kendoEditorControl.value());
    };
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I am not able to resolve this issue. I am experiencing same issue. I have also tried steps at following answer: Kendo UI Editor Events in Angularjs